# Defined function is not looping over data?

Tags: python, arrays, loops, haversine

I am trying to create a two dimmensional array that finds the distance between  stations.

Example of what I am trying to get:

[image]

I defined distance as:

```
def distance(origin, destination):
    lat1, lon1 = origin
    lat2, lon2 = destination
    radius = 6371 # km

    dlat = math.radians(lat2-lat1)
    dlon = math.radians(lon2-lon1)
    a = math.sin(dlat/2) * math.sin(dlat/2) + math.cos(math.radians(lat1)) \
        * math.cos(math.radians(lat2)) * math.sin(dlon/2) * math.sin(dlon/2)
    c = 2 * math.atan2(math.sqrt(a), math.sqrt(1-a))
    d = radius * c

    return d
```

As well as the haversine function as:

```
def distance_harvesine(df):

    # I'll use a dictionary because it doesn't need to have a pre-defined size.
    
    dict_distance = {}
    
    df_copy = df.copy()
    
    for i, row in df_copy.iterrows():
        list_distance = []
        
        lon1 = df_copy['longitude'][i]
        lat1 = df_copy['latitude'][i]
        
        origin = (lat1,lon1)

        for j, row in df_copy.iterrows():
            lon2 = df_copy['longitude'][j]
            lat2 = df_copy['latitude'][j]
            
            destination = (lat2,lon2)
            
            try:
                dist = distance(origin, destination)
            except:
                dist = 100000000000
                                
            list_distance.append(dist)
            
            
        dict_distance[i] = list_distance
            
            

    distance_matrix = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dict_distance)

    return distance_matrix
```

I have a dataframe that includes the latitude and longitude of each station but when I try to build the two dimmensional array it returns only the except.

df_H = distance_harvesine(df)

returned array df_H

[image]

I am not sure where the issue is comming from so I apolagize if I made a stupid mistake in the code or the post.

Comment: yeah, so, what is your question? A bare `except` is a horrible practice, because it *silences all errors*. So maybe remove that and see what the errors are?

Comment: Why do you need to make a copy of the dataframe? You never modify it.

Comment: `scikit-learn` has Haversine distance as one of the available metrics. I's use their implementation of the Haversine rather than re-inventing the wheel.